# deriving table size in SQL DW

Tags: azure-synapse

I am trying to derive the table size in SQL DW and Initially we were using below SQL to get the size.

```
SELECT 
 two_part_name    ,    SUM(row_count)                as table_row_count    ,    SUM(reserved_space_GB)        as table_reserved_space_GB    ,    SUM(data_space_GB)            as table_data_space_GB    ,    SUM(index_space_GB)            as table_index_space_GB    ,    SUM(unused_space_GB)        as table_unused_space_GB    FROM dbo.vTableSizes    GROUP BY two_part_name     ;
```

The output of this table for a particular table is 
   two_part_name    table_row_count table_reserved_space_GB table_data_space_GB 
    table_index_space_GB    table_unused_space_GB
   Dim_Inventory_Hierarchy  48024330    6.781504    6.77496 0   0.006544

> > Which is 6.7GB for 48M records

But while I queried the table size using below query

```
select sum(size_in_bytes)/1024/1024/1024    size_in_GB,sum(total_rows),sum(deleted_rows)     FROM sys.pdw_nodes_column_store_row_groups rg     JOIN sys.pdw_nodes_tables pt ON rg.object_id = pt.object_id AND    rg.pdw_node_id = pt.pdw_node_id AND pt.distribution_id = rg.distribution_id    JOIN sys.pdw_table_mappings tm ON pt.name = tm.physical_name    INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON tm.object_id = t.object_id    WHERE t.name = 'Dim_Inventory_Hierarchy'
```

For the same table, it is returning (~1GB )

size_in_GB  (No column name)    (No column name)
1   48024330    0

> > which is ~1GB for the same 48M records in pdw_nodes_column_store_row_groups table?

So - I am trying to understand, which one is accurate and needs to be considered for estimating the table size ?

Regards,
Aravind

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using sp_spaceused?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-spaceused-transact-sql